# How to dismiss modal view on viewDidLoad

Tags: ios4, viewdidload

I'm creating a lib for Twitter XAuth sign in and I've got everything to work pretty nicely. Except, the application won't dismiss the modal view on the viewDidLoad method unless I use a timer to dismiss it within .5 seconds. Is there a way to dismiss a modal view from viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

According to apple's doc it is not good to call viewDidLoad each & every time. It should be called only once within the life cycle of the page.

As far as dismissal is concerned, you can make your own method & call it at appropriate place .

```
-(void)TakeMeOut
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope that will work...

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.superView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Firstly, which viewDidLoad are you wanting to dismiss from? The modalView? So as soon as the model view loads you want it to dismiss? Maybe you can give more info about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yea, from the modal view that is being loaded I'm able to check whether the user is already logged in. If they're already logged in, I want the modal to get dismissed.

Comment: I updated the answer to do the dismiss from within the modal view. If it still not working for you try moving the dismiss into viewWillAppear.